# Command “W” shows that my TTY and FROM are both “tty2”

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, filesystems, users, ip-address

I use dual boot windows and Ubuntu on a thinkpad T14 and in my terminal (in the Ubuntu graphical interface) command w shows that my TTY and FROM are both tty2 not sure how this is possible

I understand how my TTY could be tty2 that all makes sense but the confusion is why my from is not displaying the ip or host name of the user logged in

Comment: Why should it display an IP address or hostname? Are you actually logged in remotely? (You don't say.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.